# Which mining software/script provides the greatest MHash/sec and power efficiency balance?

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-software

Hopefully this is not too specific..

Which mining software/script provides the greatest MHash/sec and power efficiency balance? (I'm currently using an old version of phoenix miner)

Preferably for the 5xxx series of cards, but if some mining programs are generally more efficient than others in terms of MHash/sec to power usage ratio, those are also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: My understanding is that it differs for each piece of hardware, and the OS may affect things too, which complicates things. Because of this, the usefulness of any answers to this question will likely reduce over time (as older hardware becomes obsolete). But others seem to have voted it up...

Comment: @HighlyIrregular good point(s). It was a bad question but I was interested in asking to find out if there was a general trend of some being more efficient than others.

Comment: @SeanChapman I think you'll find very little difference between the popular miners, as long as you use a recent version. That point is important though, older versions tend to have less performance.

Comment: It seems that way. However, I have had reduced performance with some of the newer versions of phoenix that's why I stuck to an older version. I think the problems with that have been fixed by now in 1.7 though. I am using a custom kernel so that helps also.

Comment: poclmb always had superior speed for me on 6970's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with a 6990 rig is that m0mchil’s Python OpenCL GPU miner is the most efficient one for me.

But I would try them out on a 12 hour basis, and do a comparison. Maximum output might be very different between software/hardware combos. Would love to see the results.